# How does Minitab calculate UCL/LCL?

Tags: statistics, minitab

Sorry this is a very basic question, but the UCL/LCL of the chart doesn't line up with the UCL/LCL I would calculate and I'd like to understand why.

[image: C chart of No. of Errors]
[image: Descriptive Statistics of No. of Errors]
[image: Minitab support on how to calculate UCL/LCL]

Based on the descriptive statistics, std dev is 13.59, mean is 63.17, UCL should be 103.94
Instead the c chart has 87.01 which would imply std dev of ~7.94

I just want to understand why/how they are getting a different value.

Sorry for the simple question, I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: Interesting question, but it's more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com, I think. Also, since this has to do with exactly how Minitab computes the bounds, you might need to ask in a Minitab-specific forum; perhaps a web search will find one.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try posting it over there.